# com.google.common.collect.Sets.SetView bug or feature?

Tags: java, collections, guava

Hello I've this piece of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<Integer>();
    set1.add(1);
    set1.add(2);
    set1.add(3);
    set1.add(4);
    set1.add(5);

    set2.add(4);
    set2.add(5);
    set2.add(6);
    set2.add(7);
    set2.add(8);

    SetView<Integer> x = Sets.intersection(set1, set2);
    set1.removeAll(x);
    set2.removeAll(x);
}
```

and it throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:841)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:877)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$7.computeNext(Iterators.java:627)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:141)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:136)
    at java.util.AbstractSet.removeAll(AbstractSet.java:142)
    at com.Main2.main(Main2.java:30)
```

is this a normal? or a small bug...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`SetView`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.SetView.html) is a *view* of the intersection of these sets, not a copy. From the Guava docs:

> An unmodifiable view of a set which may be backed by other sets; this
>   view will change as the backing sets do.

So, when you call `set1.removeAll(x)` and pass in the view, you're essentially trying to remove from `set1` while looping over part of itself. This is the reason for the [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).

To achieve what you're trying to do, have a look at [`SetView.immutableCopy()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.SetView.html#immutableCopy%28%29).

For example:

```
SetView<Integer> intersectionView = Sets.intersection(set1, set2);
ImmutableSet<Integer> intersectionCopy = intersectionView.immutableCopy();
set1.removeAll(intersectionCopy);
set2.removeAll(intersectionCopy);
```

Comment: sounds ok; but if I do the immutableCopy(), it i'll remove my objects from the view no? this way I cant do removeAll from my 2 sets... is it better to do new HashSet(SetView)?

Comment: it works thanks a lot; i was doing this: set1.removeAll(x.immutableCopy());
set2.removeAll(x.immutableCopy()); thanks for your time.