# Java Set "ConcurrentModificationException"

Tags: java, exception, concurrency

At oldSet.removeAll(deleted); this exception is thrown

> ConcurrentModificationException

I add "synchronized" keyword but no change!!

```
Set<Employees> deleted;

Set<Employees> oldSet = new TreeSet<Employees>(new EmployeeComparator());
oldSet.addAll(employeesListDB);

Set<Employees> newSet = new TreeSet<Employees>(new EmployeeComparator());
newSet.addAll(employeesList);      

 try{      

     deleted = Sets.difference(oldSet, newSet);

    Set<Employees> added = Sets.difference(newSet, oldSet);

    ***oldSet.removeAll(deleted);***
    oldSet.addAll(added);        

}catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

I also tried the iterator but the same exception appears:

```
Iterator it = oldSet.iterator();
            Employees e;
            while(it.hasNext())
            {
                e= (Employees)it.next();
                if(oldSet.contains(e))
                    oldSet.iterator().remove();
            }
```

Comment: This has a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496180/concurrent-modification-exception).

Comment: nope, it doesn't solve my problem, I am using Set not List!

Comment: Using an iterator is the key for it.

Comment: I think the problem here is with wrong usage of the Google Collections API. Assuming you are using `Sets` of the Google collections API, the problem is that `Sets.difference` returns a view backed by the original sets. Now when you're calling `removeAll` you iterate over `oldSet` while (concurrently) modifying it. Using `immutableCopy` should do the trick.

    `deleted = Sets.difference(oldSet, newSet).immutableCopy();`

Comment: Actual duplicate should be this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490901/com-google-common-collect-sets-setview-bug-or-feature

Comment: Yes @michaelLang ....immutableCopy(); solves my problem ... many thanks

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490901/com-google-common-collect-sets-setview-bug-or-feature

Answer (score 2):

The `ConcurrentModificationException` is not linked to a synchronization (multithread) problem.

**From javadoc:** *This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.... Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread...*

It happens for example if you iterate over a `Collection` (using iterator) and you change the `Collection` at the same time (adding or removing elements for example).

Comment: How can i over come it on Set

Comment: Here is the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490901/com-google-common-collect-sets-setview-bug-or-feature